# Dynamically Added Controls Do Not Display

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using the code listing below to dynamically add labels to a new tab page.

```
    Private Sub PopulateForm(ByVal TabName As String)
    ' This sub will create all of the databound controls on the new tab we have just created.
    'MessageBox.Show(TabName)
    Dim x As Integer = 1
    Dim y As Integer = 10
    Dim NewLabel As Label
    For x = 1 To 243 ' Current number of recipe elements.
        NewLabel = New Label
        NewLabel.Name = "Label" & x
        NewLabel.Location = New Point(10, y)
        NewLabel.Text = "Hello - " & x
        NewLabel.Visible = True
        Me.tabMain.TabPages(TabName).Controls.Add(NewLabel)
        y += 10
    Next
    Me.tabMain.TabPages(TabName).Refresh()
End Sub
```

My issue is that only the first label is shown on the tab page. None of the others are visible, and by visible i mean i cant see them, you can see I have set the visible property to true!

Please advise...

Comment: 10 is only a magic number when you count fingers.  These labels are entirely to close to each other,  they overlap each other and you can only see the text of the top one.  Do yourself a favor and get this right, you never want to add 243 labels.  Use ListBox or ListView, they take care of positioning the text correctly and provide the scrollbar you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a test showing that the labels are indeed added. The problem is that they overlap so that they hide each other's text.

I added this declaration in the form class

```
Private m_random As New Random()
```

Then I added this statement to the label creation

```
NewLabel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(m_random.Next(255), m_random.Next(255), m_random.Next(255))
```

The result I got was

[image]

My suggestion

```
y += NewLabel.Height
```

---

You might want to arrange your lables in rows and columns. You can do it like this:

```
Private Sub PopulateForm(ByVal TabName As String)
    Const NumLables = 243
    Const Rows As Integer = 20, ColumnWidth = 65, RowHeight = 20

    For i As Integer = 0 To NumLables - 1
        Dim column = i \ Rows
        Dim row = i Mod Rows
        Dim NewLabel = New Label With {
            .Name = "Label" & i,
            .Location = New Point(10 + column * ColumnWidth, 10 + row * RowHeight),
            .Text = "Hello - " & i,
            .Visible = True,
            .AutoSize = True
        }
        Me.tabMain.TabPages(TabName).Controls.Add(NewLabel)
    Next
End Sub
```